# Is it a good practice to save "dependent value" in the database?

Tags: database, architecture

We are developing a game that has heroes and soldiers. All of them can level up. However, as they leveled up, different algorithms are used to get their attributes for their next level.

- For heroes, their attributes are fixed values configured by designers. That is, for every level 3 mage, their attributes are totally identical.
- For other soldiers, their attributes are generated using a formula in the script, with some random noise. That is, two rabbit of the same level are not the same.

As we develop, we first implement the soldier part, then the hero part. For soldiers, as their attribute values are generated, we store each soldier attributes into the database. As the development goes on, we did the same for heroes. But is it a good practice? I mean actually we can get all the attributes from designers XML file as long as level and class are provided, save all attributes to the database seems a kind of repeat. We are taught to avoid repeat, aren't we?

For more, we have some bag grids unlocked for every 5 levels as the hero levels up, is it good to save those unlock information to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of the thumb coming from experience, if you **store value in database**, it should have **priority over any default values**. If it is the case, the design is correct. If no, it's a redundance, which should be avoided. How would future developers react if they notice that the values in the game are other from those stored in database? The first expected reaction would be - oh, there's an error, we need to fix it.

Comment: I got what you mean, but the problem here is, we stored information exactly the same as in XML files. Is it good that we do not store that and just read it from XML files?

Comment: If in case of difference between database and XML you would take the value from XML, than better not store that value in database.